# HTML concatenating a span within img tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, concatenation

I have an image tag in html which was previously referencing an image from a php array. I have recently updated this to a javascript object so I can use an AJAX request

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo $arrayElement[item]; ?>.gif">

<script>
    document.getElementById('item').innerHTML = this.processingData['item'];
</script>
```

I have tried:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo "<span id='item'></span>"; ?>.gif">
```

and the end result I want is:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/[nameOfImage].gif">
```

Comment: What value `this.processingData['item']` will have ?

Comment: If you will be loading the image with JavaScript, there is no need to do any PHP processing. Just write `<img id='item'>`. Or do I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay it's an array which contains another copy of the same image as $arrayElement but in javascript rather than php

Comment: `<img src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo "<span id='item'></span>"; ?>.gif">` ... that really does make *no* sense whatsoever.

Comment: so programmatically, set `img.src = "http://www.example.com/images/"+nameOfImage+".gif";`

Comment: Give the image an id, e.g. `<img id="piccy" ... />` then (since you've tagged this with jQuery) you can change the `src` on the fly with `$('#piccy').attr('src', this.processingData['item']);` ... is that sort of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of what i understand there is no need to put html tags in there. what you need to echo in there is pure and simple the image name

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo $arrayElement[item]; ?>.gif">
```

was correct. now if you need to affect the src attribute in javascript, simply give it a handle (an id would work if the image is unique within it's page) like this

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo $arrayElement[item]; ?>.gif">
```

and then refer to it in javascript

```
var img = document.getElementsById("myImage");
img.src = "anyValidImgUrl";
```

if you get your image url from the ajax query, use the upper code snippet in your ajax callback. if you are using jquery, chainging the image url is done as follows

```
$(".myImage").attr("src","anyValidImgUrl");
```